# Is the coworkers salary question on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

[Is it a good practice - when everybody in office are aware of co-workers salary?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/is-it-a-good-practice-when-everybody-in-office-are-aware-of-co-workers-salary)

Is this question on topic?  I saw a comment asking that question and as I reread the question I think that this is off topic.   I'm voting to close.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FAQ states

> people who want to be financially
>   literate, find ways to save money,
>   minimize taxes, invest wisely, plan
>   for retirement, etc. Also for
>   financially-savvy amateurs,
>   DIY-investors & personal finance pros

I don't see this question falling into that range.  I have also spent a few moments here wonder how I would rewrite the FAQ and I am not sure I would.  I am torn because it is an interesting question, but it is honestly a business / start-up question not a financial one.

Comment: agreed.  off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Good point.  After some thought, I agree, and I just cast my vote to close too.

While I think *some* business questions could be on-topic – e.g. relating to *self-employment*, as being close to the individual / personal end of the spectrum – I do think questions about business practices in general and in larger companies should be off-topic, **unless those practices directly impact one's *personal finances* and it is that impact that is being asked about.**

For instance, a question asking about a company's across-the-board salary reductions may be on topic if an individual is asking how to cope with that.  Or, even a question about "how can I negotiate my salary in a company where salaries are public knowledge?"  The subject matter is related to the question under the microscope in this case, but asking about the practice from an *individual's* perspective.  I'd say that would work here.

But in this case as it is written, the question seems to be asking **"what's better for the company?"** .. So I don't see the personal finance angle.  I'm sure there'll be a Stack Exchange 2.0 site for business practices, at some point.  Belongs there.

Comment: I agree that the fundamental issue with this question is the wording.  That said a question like this, which could be answered objectively, may be useful to a person's decision to stay with a company or not.  If someone were to ask about a situation which is a clear indication of company's impending demise, it would be useful from a personal finance angle; even if it were more of a career related question.

Answer (score 2):

I might be inclined to call it marginally on topic if it didn't have the addition problem of being worded so the answers will be completely subjective. Specifically the "is it a good practice" part.

If it were re-written in the context of "What are the pros/cons of me implementing this within my business" I might be inclined to let it slide.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree it is slightly off topic in regards to personal finance, it has garnered a lot of discussion from users and makes for an interesting pseudo-financial topic. I think it should remain open.

Comment: Just because it is popular doesn't mean it should stay open.  This tends to lead to more of the same.

Comment: To play devil's advocate for a moment. Technically what is on/off topic is ultimately decided by the community, not necessarily a single moderator or application of a hard rule. So a popular question that is technically off-topic question has a decent chance of surviving. I am often swayed away from voting to close an off-topic question if it has a lot of upvotes.